# В bootstrap charts не меняется цвет линий в канве

Tags: bootstrap

есть такой набор параметров в бутстрап чартах

```
var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        },

    ]
};
```

но при попытке сделать с другим цветом (синим) вот так

```
var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(48,165,255,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(48,165,255,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(48,165,255,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(48,165,255,1)",
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        },

    ]
};
```

ничего не происходит( кто знает как сделать нужный цвет?

Comment: Соберите рабочую, ну или почти рабочую демку кода, тогда будет больше шансов что ответят по существу. По одним параметрам ничего не определишь. Сами параметры на первый взгляд правильные.

Comment: кроме парметров я ничего менял, демка тут - https://mdbootstrap.com/javascript/charts/

Comment: все правильно работает но цвет линий не меняется

Comment: Я имею ввиду рабочую демку, в которой можно параметры поменять. Чтобы на ней проверить. ))

Comment: дело в том что я тупо скопировал все оттуда и ничего пока не добавлял и не менял